# Visual studio 2017 uninstall failed

Tags: uninstall, visual-studio

Hey guys i had Visual Studio 2017 community installed.

When i uninstalled it from control panel it said uninstallation failed error after a while of uninstalling.

Now its not present in control panels programs list but all the files of visual studio are stil present in the system.

How can i remove all the studio files and registry entries completely off my system ?

As it is not present in the list of programs i cant uninstall it again.
Many visual studio files are present in C drive like Visual Studio folder in Program Files and Program Files(x86) folder.

Comment: The unfortunate truth is that once the install/uninstall routines fail, you need to reinstall Windows. Visual Studio consists of thousands of components that you cannot hope to remove manually.

Comment: Thats very sad. Thanks though.

Comment: "How can i remove all the studio files and registry entries completely off my system ?" - Attempt to install VS2017 again then uninstall it.

Comment: Ill try that bro.